# Format link element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

[image]

I need to style right element as it is on picture, but when I use 'pull-right' class, it for some reason affects also width of bottom element.

```
<a class="pull-right">My link</a>
<div class="input-group margin-top-md">
    <!--->It is bottom element <--->
</div>
```

Comment: Did you already looked up for the margin/padding from your top right element?

Comment: what exactly I should check?

Comment: I think you've got a margin or padeding right on that element, so when you pull right it goes down..use the inspect element from your browser with right click or F12 on that element to see what's going on

Comment: Already checked it, no extra margin or padding

Comment: Try to add a margin auto 0px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of `float: right`if you have forgot to set the `position` of a previous element.  If you change the position of the top left container to `position: absolute` you will see the link move to the top but still floated to the right.

I would recommend styling this using CSS flex instead.

```css
.pull-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.test {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.test1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.test2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.input-group {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <div class="test1">

  </div>

  <div class="test2">
    <a class="pull-right">My link</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="input-group margin-top-md">

</div>
```